# Storing and reading DatePicker values from shared preferences not working

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm trying to allow a user to select a date. This date is then saved into shared prefences, and is used as the countdown date for a countdown timer on the next activity. I am able to save the "name" of the event but not the date, the values returned are just the default.

Storing Date:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
    int year = datePicker.getYear();


    editor.putString("day", String.valueOf(day));
    editor.putInt("month", month);
    editor.putInt("day", year);
    editor.commit();
```

Retrieving date:

```
       SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    String dayEvent = prefs.getInt("day",0);
    int monthEvent = prefs.getInt("month",0);
    int yearEvent = prefs.getInt("year",0);

    String eventString = (dayEvent + "-" + monthEvent+ "-" + yearEvent);


    TextView testDate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testDate);
    testDate.setText(eventString);
    return eventString;
```

- The output being 0-0-0 from May 1st 2017, being selected.

I'm not sure if it matters, but these two are in separate classes.
Thanks

Shared Preferences:

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Date_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Comment: You use different SharedPreferences for save and load. Why?

Comment: Remember that in Java all code must be inside a class. I appreciate that you are trying to show the minimal amount of code necessary to illustrate your problem. However, in leaving out the `class ??? extends ???` lines and the method declarations, you leave out some necessary information that may be needed to answer your question. Specifically, it is helpful to know if the code is in `onCreateView()` of a `Fragment` subclass or if it is in `onCreate()` of an `Activity` class or if it is in some other class all together. You can most easily show this information with code rather than words.

Answer (score 0):

When you save your preferences you should pass a name :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// open editor and commit() or apply()
```

Then to retrieve the data you get the shared preference the exact same way.

You can also use the `getDefaultSharedPreferences` which are common to all your activities :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

**EDIT :**

## Without using default shared pref

#### Save

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DATE_AND_STUFF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.apply();
```

#### Retrieve

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DATE_AND_STUFF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = prefs.getString("key", "defaultValue");
```

## Using default shared pref

#### Save

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(FirstActivity.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.apply();
```

#### Retrieve

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SecondActivity.this);
String value = prefs.getString("key", "defaultValue");
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, what would be "context" then? in the DefaultsharedPreferences

Comment: I have added my shared preferences I want to use in (shown in question now), but still get the error/ 0-0-0

Comment: @Corey The answer to that entirely depends on which class contains this code. Please edit your question to show which methods and classes contain each section of code.

Comment: Every `Activity` provides a `context`, chich contains global information about the application environment : `getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this)`

Comment: You created two times a SharedPreference object... I'll write a more complete example, just a second